# Find the maximum possible energy for a beta-particle decay-chain

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

So I have this problem where I'm supposed to find the maximum possible energy for a $\beta$-particle in the following decay-chain:

The first decay:
$$^{90}Sr\rightarrow ^{90}Y + \beta^- + \bar{v}_e$$
The second decay:
$$^{90}Y\rightarrow ^{90}Zr + \beta^- + \bar{v}_e$$

$^{90}Sr$ decays to the stable $^{90}Zr$ nucleus after two $\beta$-decays.

For the first $\beta^-$-decay we have $E_{\beta^-, max}=0.5459$ MeV and for the second $\beta^{-}$-decay we have $E_{\beta^-, max}=2.2785$ MeV.
Does this mean that the maximum possible energy for a $\beta$-particle in the given decay-chain is 2.2785 MeV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

(Some questions are easy to answer :) )